# Is there any way to execute"CLS" in Turbo assembler? And I have some problem with dl,10

Tags: assembly, tasm

Hello I'm new in assembly language and I have 2 questions:
1. Is there any built-in "CLS" in turbo assembler or any way to achieve "CLS" results?
2. I don't know why, when I move dl,10 to a PROC named createLine and call the PROC in addMenu PROC it didn't show what I want.

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.data
    main_menu db "Please choose what will you do?",10,13
              db "1. Add item",10,13
              db "2. exit",10,13
              db "Please enter your choice: $",10,13

    add_menu db "Food:",10,13
             db "1. Nasi Lemak :  RM 2",10,13
             db "2. Nasi Ayam  :  RM 3",10,13
             db "3. Nasi Goreng:  RM 2",10,13
             db "4. Mee Goreng :  RM 3",10,13
             db "Beverage:",10,13
             db "5. Air Suam   :  RM 1",10,13
             db "6. Tea O'Ais  :  RM 2",10,13
             db "7. Ais Limau  :  RM 2",10,13
             db "8. Barley Ice :  RM 3",10,13
             db "Please enter your choice: $",10,13
.
.
createLine PROC
    mov     dl,10
    mov     ah,2h
    int     21h
createLine endp

jmpToNoStock PROC
    call noStock
jmpToNoStock endp

addMenu PROC
    call    createLine
    lea     dx,add_menu
    mov     ah,9h
    int     21h
.
.
.
```

[image]

Comment: Please ask one question per question.  That said, there is no builtin `CLS` function.  You can achieve the effect using [INT 10h/AH=06](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/121-int_10h_06h__scroll_up___clear_screen_rectangle.html).

Comment: Your procedure `createLine` writes LineFeed to console window, see http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2554.htm, and then it continues with `jmpToNoStock`. If you  want `createLine` be callable, append `ret` just below `int 21h`.

Comment: owhh I see thankyouuu both of u, I appreciate it.